# PrimeVue DataTable reset sort

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I'm using PrimeVue 3.11.1 with Vue 3.

I have a data table that is using lazy loading and when I reload the dataset I need to clear any sorting that was previously used.

I'm using resetPage which is clearing the paging, and the lazy params are being reset, but I cannot clear the sorted column.

Answer (score -1):

`sortField="initSortField"` - clean after load fresh fetch without reload page.

Comment: Hello at stack**overflow**. Please see the [help page on expected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) on *chitchat*.